# Determine if a point lies in a quadrangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons, quadrilateral

I have a [quadrangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkVmO.png) which sides consist of parts of rays, and I only know the coordinates of two points on each ray.

I need to determine if a point $(x,y)$ lies in such quadrangle.

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrrWg.png), I painted the sides of the quadrangle red in case you don't understand about what quadrangle I'm talking.

Comment: Can you determine the intersection points of the rays?

Comment: I multplied LHS of their equations as following. Can you check the sign of this product? And the logic?
$$(\frac{x}{5}+ \frac{y}{3}-1).(\frac{x}{4}+ \frac{y}{-7}-1).(\frac{x}{-8}+ \frac{y}{-12}-1).(\frac{x}{5}+ \frac{y}{-2}-1) $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(x_a, y_a), B(x_b, y_b), C(x_c, y_c)$ and $D(x_d, y_d)$ form the quadrilateral $ABCD$ with area $S$ and let $P$ be the point you've chosen.

Calculate the areas of the triangles $\triangle PAB, \triangle PBC, \triangle PCD$ and $\triangle PDA$, for instance, with the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula). Let their sum be $S'$. Then

\begin{align*}
S'=S&\implies P\text{ lies inside }ABCD\\
S'>S&\implies P\text{ lies outside } ABCD
\end{align*}